# How to get PostgreSQL tables total disk size under a schema

Tags: postgresql, size

Our PostgreSQL database was getting bigger and we wanted to identify what tables are guilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT table_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(table_name)),pg_total_relation_size(table_name), table_schema
FROM information_schema.tables t
where table_schema='main'
  and table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Output sample:

table1,25 GB

table2,14 GB

table3,11 GB

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT 
    schemaname || '.' || tablename AS full_table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT 
        schemaname,
        tablename,
        pg_total_relation_size(schemaname || '.' || tablename) AS total_bytes
    FROM pg_tables
    WHERE schemaname = 'Name of Schema you want'
) AS table_sizes
ORDER BY total_bytes DESC;
```

You can modify the where clause to get the disk size of the tables under the schema.